# adding break line to expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reportviewer, expression

I have an expression statement to display content for a text box for a reportviewer but went blank when trying to add a carriage return or a new line between the two expression. My expression as follows:

```
=Format(Fields!LastDateVisited.Value, "d")+ " "+Fields!LastVisitType.Value
```

Instead of the space i want to make it a new line. I tried "\n" but didn't work, any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a end of line character should work: '\n'

Comment: Format(Fields!LastDateVisited.Value, "d")+ System.Environment.NewLine+Fields!LastVisitType.Value

Comment: I had to wait for a couple minutes before it allowed me to do that since the question was posted and answered quickly. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use following :

```
= Fields!FirstField1.Value + System.Environment.NewLine + Fields!MyField2
```

Answer (score 0):

in your placeholder properties (Expr page) change the markup type to html